# How to recover my account if my openid provider is closed?

Tags: support, openid

Ok...I just found out that my openid provider (myid.net) has closed.

I can't no loger login with my real account. How do I recover my account?

Comment: Isn't this your real account? You've got a fair bit of rep on SO.

Comment: omg...i think i'm on cookie. If I log out, I think I will not able to login again.

Comment: Just go to your profile, click on `mylogins` and then `add more logins`

Comment: @AshRj // Thanks AshRj. I just linked it and it's working. One problem is that..If I use google account, all of my questions are gone in profile.

Answer (score 3):

As you are logged in, its not so much a problem.

You simply need to go to your profile and click on `my logins`.

[image]

Then click on `add more logins`

[image]

And you will be taken to the main login page where you can add other Openids.

---

[image]

Comment: This is strange. When I go to my profile, I see that I have a fair amount of SO reps. When I click "Stack Overflow", I see that my username becomes "user45326". When I click my profile on SO, I see 0 questions and "user45326" has 1 rep.